# Mi aplicación de Laravel no se puede conectar al servidor de redis de Google Cloud

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, redis

Tengo una aplicación de Laravel ya montada en Google Cloud, las necesidades del proyecto me orillaron a usar `caché` con `redis`. Todo funciona bien en mi máquina local, pero cuando subo cambios para que funcione en producción pero tengo el error `Connection timed out [tcp://ip_redis:6379]`

Mis configuraciones en el `yaml` que es como el `env` pero para Google Cloud:

```
 REDIS_CLIENT: predis
 REDIS_HOST: ip_redis
 REDIS_PASSWORD: null
 REDIS_PORT: 6379
```

Tengo creado el servidor de `redis` en Google Cloud también, con las siguientes características:

```
Nivel
Básico

Ubicación
us-central1-a

Red autorizada
default (my_project)

Rango de direcciones IP
rango_ip/29
```

Y al momento de inicializar la configuración del comando `gcloud init` me aseguré de configurarla en la misma zona que el servidor de redis (`us-central1-a`) e hice el deploy de la aplicación.

Me siguió apareciendo el mismo error.

Así que investigué un poco más y me metí a `Redes de VPC > Firewall` y creé dos reglas para ver si eso era lo que fallaba.

La configuración de la primera regla fue (nótese que puse el mismo rango que daba el servidor de `redis`):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La segunda regla es idéntica a diferencia del tipo de tráfico, ahora la configuré a tráfico de salida.

Incluso creé una VM para probar la conexión usando `telnet` y sí tengo respuesta, sí funciona correctamente el servidor `redis`.

También, tengo implementado `CloudFlare` lo que me hizo pensar que probablemente podría estar bloqueándolo de alguna manera, pero añadí una regla de excepción con la IP de servidor (`ip_redis`) para permitir la conexión, pero no resultó, al parecer `CloudFlare` no influye en esta conexión.

Además, vi esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62041203/6241464), sobre modificar la parte de `post-install-cmd` del archivo `composer.json`, pero mi archivo no tenía ese apartado, decidí añadirlo a los `scripts` de todos modos, tampoco funcionó. Marca el mismo error

Pero aún después de todo esto no he podido hacer que la aplicación de Laravel se conecte al servidor de redis.

Comment: ¿Esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62041203/6459968) no te es de ayuda?

Comment: No, ya había visto esa respuesta pero mi composer.json no tiene ni siquiera el apartado de post-install-cmd :(

Comment: ¿Y no intentaste agregando dicho apartado?

Comment: Sí, resultó en el mismo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que se necesitaba era un conector especial, que se crea en Red de VPC > Acceso a VPC sin servidores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y hacer click en crear conector:

Con especial cuidado en configurar la región, para hacerla coincidir con la región de tu aplicación.

El la red, default.

En el rango IP, podemos podemos poner la sugerencia que viene debajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muy importante también es activar la opción `AUTH` para el servidor de `Redis`, si no, aparecerán errores de autenticación. Una vez activada la opción, hay que copiar el `String AUTH` que te da Google Cloud cuando ves los detalles de tu servidor de `Redis`. Esa cadena la pegamos en el `yaml` en la variable `REDIS_PASSWORD`.

Ahora, debemos color una configuración el `yaml` para hacer `deploy`:

```
vpc_access_connector:
    name: 'projects/mi-proyecto/locations/us-central1/connectors/conector'.
```

Ahora solo queda correr el comando para hacer `deploy`:

```
gcloud beta app deploy -v=production-cache -q
```

Hay que usar `beta` dado que alguna veces el comando normal puede ignorar el apartado de `vpc_access_connector`.

Y listo.